# How to install SectionDoubleP Python Module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, python-module

Anybody know where or how to install the python module: **SectionDoubleP** ?
I've already tried pip install but nothing ... sadly.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is this the `SectionDoubleP` you are looking for? https://github.com/joxeankoret/tahh/blob/master/evasion/SectionDoubleP.py

Comment: Posting the error that you got would be much helpful to debug.

Comment: can you provide some more context? SectionDoubleP is a python script/file not a package that you can run and install. You need to import the script from your python file/script by importing.

Comment: Hey Guys, thanks for all the quick answers.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "peCloak.py", line 40, in <module>
    from SectionDoubleP import *
ImportError: No module named SectionDoubleP

Comment: I don't know how to get the module SectionDoubleP onto my Linux system so that I can execute my Python program.